# APPFabricServices Crashing

Tags: appfabric-cache

AppFabricCaching services are crashing with the below msg logged:

```
AppFabric Caching service crashed.{Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.ConfigStoreException: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.) ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified network name is no longer available
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SqlServerCustomProviderCore.GetEntries(Object transactionContext, String type)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SqlServerCustomProviderCore.GetEntries(Object transactionContext, String type)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SqlServerCustomProvider.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<PerformOperation>b__0()
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SqlServerCustomProvider.PerformOperation(Action action)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SqlServerCustomProvider.PerformOperation[TResult](Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.ClusterConfigDictionaryReader.GetConfigs[T](String type)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.ServiceConfigurationManager.InitializeHostsData(IClusterConfigurationReader globalConfig)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.ServiceConfigurationManager.InitializeDataFromGlobalConfig()
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.VelocityWindowsService.StartService(Boolean deleteTKT)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.VelocityWindowsService.StartServiceCallback(Object context)}
```

any pointers are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This message is very important

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the
>   server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name
>   is no longer available.) ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
>   transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the
>   server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name
>   is no longer available.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:
>   The specified network name is no longer available

This error suggests that the Sql Server instance hosting the cluster configuration is no longer available. As the configuration location can be a single point of failure, it have to be always available.

Check the configured connection string in DistributedCacheService.exe.config under `Program Files\ Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server`.